# Store in array single value produced by each step in a for loop VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, for-loop, montecarlo, vba

I have exactly the problem stated in this discussion:

[Storing and Printing values in Array - VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329235/storing-and-printing-values-in-array-vba)

but I need to see them through debug, not only print them.

Substantially, I created this code:

```
Sub Montecarlo()

Dim X0, Xi, T, dt, m, s, Zi, dXi As Double
Dim ArraydXi() As Variant

X0 = 10
T = 5
dt = 1
m = 0.01
s = 0.2

n = T / dt

For i = 1 To n
    Zi = Application.WorksheetFunction.Norm_S_Inv(Rnd())
    dXi = m * dt + s * (dt) ^ (1 / 2) * Zi
    ArraydXi() = Array(dXi)
Next

SumElements = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ArraydXi())

Xi = X0 + SumElements

End Sub
```

Anyway there are two problems here:

1) when I go through debug, into `ArraydXi()` I see it is stored only the last (the fifth in this case) `dXi` value of the for loop, while I want to be stored all the five `dXi` values of each step of the for loop and

2) consequently in the `SumElements` variable, there is no trace of the sum of the five elements that should be stored into the array.

May I ask any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please let me know wheter this solves the problem or not.

```
Sub Montecarlo()

Dim X0, Xi, T, dt, m, s, Zi, dXi As Double
Dim ArraydXi() As Variant

X0 = 10
T = 5
dt = 1
m = 0.01
s = 0.2

n = T / dt

ReDim ArraydXi(n)
For i = 1 To n
    Zi = Application.Norm_S_Inv(Rnd())
    dXi = m * dt + s * (dt) ^ (1 / 2) * Zi
    ReDim Preserve ArraydXi(i)
    ArraydXi(i) = dXi
    Debug.Print ArraydXi(i)
Next

SumElements = Application.Sum(ArraydXi)

Xi = X0 + SumElements

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Moreno, your correction worked out perfectly, that's what I wanted!
Substantially I had to declare the i counter into the array variable, that's what I missed. Thank you very much for your help and support!

Comment: Hint: if you want to write `ArraydXi` back to a given sheet (instead of `Debug.Print`) just use this line: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").[A2].Resize(n, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ArraydXi)`

Comment: I'm mystified as to how this code can work but mine doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing a little, but at no point do you declare the size of ArraydXi, and hence you are not storing each value in a separate element. Try this.

```
Sub Montecarlo()

Dim X0, Xi, T, dt, m, s, Zi, dXi As Double
Dim ArraydXi() As Variant

X0 = 10
T = 5
dt = 1
m = 0.01
s = 0.2

n = T / dt

ReDim ArraydXi(1 To n)

For i = 1 To n
    Zi = Application.WorksheetFunction.Norm_S_Inv(Rnd())
    dXi = m * dt + s * (dt) ^ (1 / 2) * Zi
    ArraydXi(i) = dXi
Next

SumElements = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ArraydXi)

Xi = X0 + SumElements

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi SJR, thanks, I tried your solution, but when running it gives me the run-time error '9': "Subscript out of range" at the 
    ArraydXi(i) = dXi
line. How I can fix this?

Comment: Hm, what is the value of `n` and what is the value of `dXi` when it errors?

Comment: The value of n is 5, while dXi is 0,118084708163063, it stucks at the first iteration.

Comment: I can't replicate that. Have you stepped through the code to check what's going on? Perhaps comment out the Zi line, hard-code the dXi line as equal to, say, 1 and check that that works. Are you definitely using the code as posted above?

Comment: Code is working *(despite missing declarations if `Option Explicit` is not set; BTW most variables should be of type `Double` and not `Variant`)*